# Defining variable in a memory-mapped file region in C to store in-memory tree using mmap

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, mmap

#### Background:

Suppose I have an in-memory b-tree (not b+ tree) which its nodes are declared like this:

```cpp
struct node
{
int* keys;
struct node** children;
int currentNumOfKeys;
char isLeaf;
}
```

---

#### What I understand so far:

I've read using **`mmap()`** one could just map a memory region into a file and store the data, forgetting all about persistency and the next time you load the program, all the pointers are valid! Given that you either map the file into the exact same start address, or use relative offsets for your pointers!

---

#### Questions:

Now, if I want to take advantage of this, **How can I initialize an struct object inside the mapped region?**
Normally, using something like `struct node* root = (struct node*)malloc( sizeof(struct node) );` would give me arbitrary memory address, wherever OS wants.

I want something like this:

> 1- Initialize the first node of the tree in the mapped region
> 2- Change my `struct node** children` to `int children[MAX_DEGREE]` > so I can store the offset for the children nodes, from this root node
> 3- Initialize and store the next nodes in the mapped region, in some fashion that the next time the program starts, mapping the file recreate the tree without the need of sorting it

---

#### Notes:

1. **In every step, I want to avoid using swap files to make up for memory shortage or copying data into the disk (besides the mapped
   file obviously) in all kinds.**
2. I would change `struct node** children;` into something like `int children[MAX_DEGREE];` to store relative offset of every child node, from the root node.

---

###### Edited question to be more focused on one problem/question

Comment: You need to write your own allocator. Since you only need to allocate objects of one size, it can be much simpler than a full malloc-style allocator.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Abstractly speaking, what should this allocator do? Find the first free memory chunk from the mapped region, flag it as allocated, and return the address to it?
Then for initializing struct object, would simple casting work? e.g. `struct node* child = (struct node*) myAllocator( sizeof(struct node) );`

Comment: Yes something like that.

Comment: Contents of an mmap cannot take pointers.  You have to rethink your strategy and use array indices - yes it is like going back to the dark ages when pointers only existed in another world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with mmap is that it can be seen by any program that attaches to the shared memory.

```
program1    shm    program2
            XXX
&XXX ->     &XXX   this is program1's &XXX
                   In program2, &xxx is different
```

One way around it is to use arrays with indices instead of pointers.  So instead of

```
struct node
{
   struct node* first_child;
   struct node* next_node;
   ... some data;
};
```

use something like

```
struct node
{
    unsigned short ix_next_node;
    unsigned short ix_first_child;
    ... some data
};
```

If backward navigation is required, then a previous and parent node will be required.  Assuming there aren't more than 65534 nodes.  Leave the value 65535 to mean there is no node.  This way, children[MAX_DGREE] is not required since it is effectively a singly linked list.  So if the tree looks like

```
+-- 0
|   +-- 4
|   |   +-- 6
|   |   +-- 7
|   |
|   +-- 5
|
+-- 1
|   +-- 2
|
+-- 3
```

The parent, prev node, next node and child would be

```
Index parent prev  next  first
0     65535  65535 1     4
1     65535  0     3     65545
2     1      65545 65535 65535
3     65535  1     65535 65535
4     0      65535 5     65535
5     0      4     65535 65535
6     4      65535 7     65535
7     4      6     65535 65535
```

All you need to do now is to write a program to do it.

Comment: Indeed this is a good solution, thanks for your time and effort!
However, could you please explain the very first block? Couldn't memory-mapped file to be of MAP_PRIVATE (I forget the real flag! whatever it is) and with FS permissions, the file should be safe too! Am I wrong?

Comment: I've never found a use for MAP_PRIVATE.  I've normally use MAP_SHARED.  I've seen MAP_PRIVATE used in place of a memory array.  If you're going to do that, just use a memory array - don't bother with memory mapped files.   It is just a lot of extra effort for very little gain.